# How to Script Password Encryption in Veritas Cluster Server 6.0?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, veritas-cluster-server

I am (batch) scripting my Veritas Cluster Server 6.0 configuration.  The `Process` resources I am configuring need to run as user `domain\user` (the "UserName" attribute).  I have tried to enter the "Password" attribute via the command line, using the listed methods.  Any suggestions on how to script password configurations?

Method 1: Plaintext (no worky)

```
C:\>hares -modify MyResource Password mypassword
```

Method 2: vcsencrypt.exe (no worky)

```
C:\>vcsencrypt -agent domain\user
AMEmZMnMJmJMoKMoJOdMZoC
C:\>hares -modify MyResource Password AMEmPMnMBmJMoKMoFOdMFoC
```

Method 3: GUI  (works, but need scripting option)

1. Select Resource
2. Edit/enter "Password" Scalar Value
3. Accept that password will be encrypted
4. Observe hashed password shown in configuration
5. Successfully online resource

Specs:

Veritas Cluster Server: 6.0
Operating System: Windows 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: Method 2 above actually works.  The resource I was attempting to online had its own (incorrect) credentials.  Operator error.